# If its given that laplacian of a scalar field is zero, what we can tell about that scalar field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, vector-fields

What can be deduced about scalar field if its laplacian is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the laplacian is zero , the function is called **harmonic** .

You can see here the properties of a harmonic function:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function